# Are @Transactional and packagesToScan are interlinked?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

`com.service.EmployeeService` has method create `createEmployee` which calls  method under dao class i.e `com.dao.EmployeeDao(having EntityManager as dependency)`.
Now i want to make  method `createEmployee`  transactional with `@Transactional`. Is it mandatoty to declare the package `com.service`
under `packagesToScan` in spring config file ?

I mean is it mandatory to declare the package of class using `@Transactional`  under `packagesToScan` to make  it work ?

FYI I referred the [how-does-spring-transactional-really-work](http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/) to understand how spring transactions works internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Transactional is used on a class or method for the transaction management whereas packagesToScan is used by spring for scanning annotations on your entity classes

```
<property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.xyz.EntityName</value>
            </list>
        </property>
```

I used @Transactional on my DaoImpl methods(CRUD) and used packagesToScan on the entities for spring to pick.

When you use spring with hibernate it is the responsibility of the spring's class i.e org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
as in `<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">` 
 instead of Hibernate's new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()

Moreover in hibernate you use to tell hibernate to consider the entities which are using annotation as in hibrnate.cfg.xml by using

```
<mapping class="com.hiber.hr.Countries"/>
<mapping class="com.hiber.hr.Departments"/>
```

Similarly you need to tell spring the same through packagesToScan property.

Internally Spring calls the Hibernate's addAnnotatedClass method of org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration class

Hibernate method called from Spring:-

```
public Configuration addAnnotatedClass(Class annotatedClass)
   {
     XClass xClass = reflectionManager.toXClass(annotatedClass);
    metadataSourceQueue.add(xClass);
    return this;
   }
```

Comment: But my question then is why do we need `packagesToScan` when we are already using `@Entity` annotation on JPA entity. What if I don't mention the entity under `packagesToScan` and just use `@Entity` ?

Comment: I have added few more lines above to answer your comment.

Comment: Ok got it. But one more question why spring need to know of JPA entities location ? what kind of processing it does on them ?

Comment: The same kind of processing which Hibernate does on them. It is not the location but packageName.className which hibernate uses in mapping class="packageName.className" in exactly the same way Spring uses it. Spring internally delegates the same to hibernate as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Transactional makes a Spring bean method transactional.

`packagesToScan` is a property of the Spring sessionFactory / entityManagerFactory beans, that tell them where to find JPA entities.

They are completely orthogonal. Entities are not Spring beans. And transactional Spring beans are not entities that must be found by the SessionFactory / EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: I believe `packagesToScan` property is used to search the entities where `EntityManager`  needs to be injected. Right ?

Comment: No. EntityManager is not injected in entities. It's injected in Spring beans, usually DAOs/Repositories, using the PersistenceContext annotation. Nothing is injected in entities, since entities are not Spring beans.

Comment: as you said  `packagesToScan ... tell them where to find JPA entities.` So in my example of `createEmployee`  `Employee` will be the JPA entity as I have used `@Entity` . But my question then is why do we need  `packagesToScan` when we are already using `@Entity` annotation on JPA entity. What if I don't mention the entity under `packagesToScan` and just use `@Entity` ?

Comment: `@Entity` tells that a class is an entity. But there is no magic way for Spring to know all the classes which are annotated with `@Entity`. It helps you by scanning classes to find them, but to avoid scanning the entier classpath, you help it by telling it which package to scan to find them.